# C++: Weird negative integer output, most likely due to an error in the loop, but I can't seem to notice it

Tags: c++, function, loops, range

I'm writing a program which is supposed to randomly generate numbers, and then allocate them into specific ranges, depending on the number

This is the function which takes care of that:

```
void rangiranje(int arr[30], int &rang1do2k, int &rang2do3k, int &rang3do4k, int &rang4do5k) {
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    if (arr[i] >= 1000 && arr[i] <= 1999) {
        rang1do2k++;
    }
    else if (arr[i] >= 2000 && arr[i] <= 2999) {
        rang2do3k++;
    }
    else if (arr[i] >= 3000 && arr[i] <= 3999) {
        rang3do4k++;
    }
    else if (arr[i] >= 4000 && arr[i] <= 4999) {
        rang4do5k++;
    }
}
std::cout << "Stevilo dni, ko so bile okuzbe v rangu: " << std::endl;
std::cout << "1000-1999: " << rang1do2k << std::endl;
std::cout << "2000-2999: " << rang2do3k << std::endl;
std::cout << "3000-3999: " << rang3do4k << std::endl;
std::cout << "4000-4999: " << rang4do5k << std::endl; }
```

The 4000-4999 range outputs fine, but the other ones get weird negative integers like -858643
I'm certain it's an error in the loop, but I can't seem to notice it

Comment: how do u initialize the counters?

Comment: The loop is fine. Please show us how do you call this function, how do you create parameters etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize rang1do2k, rang2do3k etc. with 0 value before your loop.
Then, perhaps you don't go into any other if else than this with range 4000-4999, so all other counter will have 0 values.

```
int rang1do2k = 0;
```

Comment: such a trivial part and i missed it lol, thanks!